# mysqli_stmt_bind_param is inserting zeros in my

Tags: mysql, data-binding, statements, prepare

i`m trying to make a login form using prepare statements, but the code is includin in my sql only zeros in the fields here is my code, thank you for helping me!

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','mupcku', '123', 'dbproject');
      mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

     if(!$con){
         echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
         echo 'Cannot connect to database!';
         exit;
     } 
$sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, pass) VALUES (user_name=?, pass=?)";
       $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $pass);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

       if(!$stmt){
           echo 'Грешка!';
           die(mysqli_error($stmt));
       }
```

Comment: seems you don't have asssigned value to $username, $pass .. or is not visible ..

Answer (score 0):

This is the error which i can see `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbproject\reg.php`

Also i use this

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){

$username= trim($_POST['username']);
$pass= trim($_POST['pass']);
```

to assign values.